# Android-Reflection: Intercepting TelephonyManager.getDeviceId function at runtime

Tags: android, reflection

Some functions in library I bought call `getDeviceId()` which requires `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission. Most of the users don't want their phone number to be read so I don't want to ask this permission.

So I need to intercept `android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()` at runtime with my own function. I guess its possible using reflection but I couldn't find any elegant solution. Any suggestions ?

Comment: its totally unclear to me, what you like to archive. Do you have a lib, calling some functions from there which in place calls `TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()`?

Comment: Yes but getDeviceId() requires permission. So I want to intercept getDeviceId() function with another function at runtime

Comment: I dont think you could intercept a call from a library you dont have access to. I would suggest to simply leave out this permission in your Manifest, and surround the code with a try catch, where you do nothing

Comment: I know I can't intercept the actual code. But I think its possible to intercept a certain function using reflection.

Comment: As far as I know: No you can't intercept or override a method with reflection

Answer (score 0):

```
 String deviceId = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: I don't have access to the lib

Comment: This is accessible to every app plz create sample app with this code check .